# iPad problem with overweight GarageBand

Tags: ipad, garageband

GarageBand occupies 13 gigs, but the app itself is only a couple hundred megs. How can I delete whatever files, etc are bulking it up?

Comment: How often to you use GarageBand? Have you imported any audio samples to work with? I use BeatMaker 2 on the iPad and it takes up 23GB because of imported samples/songs and exported mixes. Just a thought. If you delete the app like konqui suggested, you will lose all of this data (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Useage at the Top you should get a list of all the Apps (may take a few to a few more Minutes)

Now Locate GarageBand and delete what you don't need anymore.

Maybe there is nothing listed then just delete GarageBand and reinstall it.